# How to make div stay centered when window resized to smaller than background width

Tags: html, css

I have a content div with a background that is centered within the wrapper container. I would like to know how to keep this background image centered, when you resize the browser window to narrower than 500px background image.

Right now, it starts to cut off the image from the right side.

http://jsfiddle.net/kon0w3t3/1/

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

div.content {
  background: url(http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lbi4ltLmYL1qb23z5o1_500.jpg) 
              no-repeat scroll center 0 transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `max-width: 100%` to your content div. This will prevent it from expanding beyond the size of the wrapper, keeping the background centered.

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

div.content {
  background: url(http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lbi4ltLmYL1qb23z5o1_500.jpg)
              no-repeat scroll center 0 transparent;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eb51hxj1/